Does Firebase Authentication offer a page for deleting user accounts?
I am using Firebase Authentication in my Android app. Google is asking me for a URL where users can delete their account. Before I create a page and host it myself, I was wondering if Firebase offers that functionality? I was not able to find anything on the Firebase README.

There is no predefined page that you can show to the user to delete their account. If you need such a page, you'll have to create it yourself based on the API to delete a user.
This API does require that the user needs to be signed in to their account, as otherwise there is no way to prevent abuse. If that is a hurdle for your use-case, you could consider making a custom backend end-point where you use the Admin SDK to delete a user. If you do this, make sure that you ensure the action is properly authorized by the user in some way that fits your requirements.
